# Failure on evaluating the nodes in PODPAC library

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, geospatial, python-traitlets

I have been following the example notebook for [PODPAC](https://github.com/creare-com/podpac-examples/blob/develop/notebooks/5-datalib/terrain-tiles.ipynb) library. However, the simplest `node.eval(coord)` fails.

The other thing I have tried is downloading the tif file from s3 into local machine and then trying to run `node.eval(node.coordinates)` based on [this](https://github.com/creare-com/podpac-examples/blob/main/notebooks/1-reading-data/raster-file.ipynb) example.

However, in both cases I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e718b03558a3> in <module>
----> 1 node.eval(c)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/podpac/core/compositor/compositor.py in eval(self, coordinates, **kwargs)
    244 
    245         # note: super().eval (not self._eval)
--> 246         output = super().eval(super_coordinates, **kwargs)
    247 
    248         if settings["DEBUG"]:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/podpac/core/node.py in eval(self, coordinates, **kwargs)
    294             self._from_cache = True
    295         else:
--> 296             data = self._eval(coordinates, **kwargs)
    297             if self.cache_output:
    298                 self.put_cache(data, item, cache_coordinates)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/podpac/core/interpolation/interpolation.py in _eval(self, coordinates, output, _selector)
     39             force_eval=True,
     40             cache_ctrl=CacheCtrl([]),
---> 41             style=self.style,
     42         )
     43         node._set_interpolation()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/podpac/core/node.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    208 
    209             # Call traitlets constructor
--> 210             super(Node, self).__init__(**tkwargs)
    211 
    212         self._traits_initialized_guard = True

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    117         if type is None:
    118             try:
--> 119                 next(self.gen)
    120             except StopIteration:
    121                 return False

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py in hold_trait_notifications(self)
   1495                 self._cross_validation_lock = False
   1496                 # Restore method retrieval from class
-> 1497                 del self.notify_change
   1498 
   1499                 # trigger delayed notifications

AttributeError: notify_change
```

Is anyone familiar with node.eval structure and potential reasons why I am not able to successfully run it in my local? I have tried installing podpac with all dependency so I don't think I am missing any package, hopefully.